# getting list of data from my controller and display it to my view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**This is my MODEL**

```
namespace Maintenance_.Models
{
    public class IndexModel
    {
        public IList<Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel> fNameList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**This is my Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessTech()
{
    TechnicianFacade _oTechFacade = new TechnicianFacade();
    Technician _oTechnician = new Technician();
    Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel _oTechModel = new Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel();
    IList<Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel> _otechList = new List<Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel>();
    var tech = _oTechFacade.getTechnicians("", _oAppSetting.ConnectionString).ToArray();
    foreach (var test in tech)
    {
        string fName = test.GetType().GetProperty("FIRSTNAME").GetValue(test, null).ToString();
        _oTechModel.firstName = fName;
        _otechList.Add(_oTechModel);
    }
    _oTechModel.fNameList = _otechList;
    return View("Index", _oTechModel);  
}
```

my controller can already save list of data in my _otechList

**My View**

```
@model Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Technician";    
}

<div id="page-wrapper">
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-lg-12">
        <h1 class= "page-header"> Technician </h1>  
    </div>
</div>
<div class = "row">
<center>           
        ...@*My Ajax code*@...
            <div style ="width:300px;height:500px; float:left;margin-left:40px;">
            <table style ="float:left;border:5px solid;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td style ="background-color:#3ba7f7; height:40px;width:100px; border-bottom:5px solid;">Technician No.</td>
                        <td style ="background-color:#3ba7f7; height:40px;width:200px; border-bottom:5px solid;">Technician Name:</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style ="background-color:#E0EBEB; height:40px;width:100px;"><a href ="#" onclick="call();" style ="text-decoration:none; text-decoration-color:black;"> T-00000031</a></td>
                 ==>    <td style ="background-color:#E0EBEB; height:40px;width:200px;"> Jerald Villaceran</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>    
                </div>                       
...
```

now, I want to change the line of code that I put a "==>" into a dynamic type of code,
can I still use foreach in my td tag or in my tr tag? Like what I have done in my controller in getting all the data from my database. or I can use the @html.displaytext()?

Comment: sorry about my title the dislay, must be display* I'm sorry, now I can't edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you need these changes:

```
@model IList<Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Technician";    
}

@foreach(var item in Model)
{
 <tr>
 <td style ="background-color:#E0EBEB; height:40px;width:100px;"><a href ="#" onclick="call();" style ="text-decoration:none; text-decoration-color:black;"> T-00000031</a></td>
 <td style ="background-color:#E0EBEB; height:40px;width:200px;"> @item.FirstName</td>
 </tr>
}
```

Comment: Is there another way to add Model IList<Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel> without deleting model Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel? Because after I changed it there's an error: "Compilation Error" >>Line 51:                     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.techNo, new { @class="form-control maintain-text", placeholder="Technician No..."})

Comment: then you have to use a partial view and render it via ajax in this current view

Comment: in my Controller I'll add this: public PartialViewResult tech(){return PartialView("Index")}, and in my view I'll add this: @ajax.actionlink().? I just don't know what to add in this ajax.actionlink. can you help me.

Comment: you can use Ajax.ActionLink this way: @Ajax.ActionLink(“Click me”, “ControllerMethod”, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = “post-loading-div”})

Answer (score 0):

try this. it will still use IndexModel as your model. you will just loop through the fNameList.

```
 @model Maintenance_.Models.IndexModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Technician";    
    }
    <table style ="float:left;border:5px solid;">

    @foreach(var item in Model.fNameList)
    {
     <tr>
     <td style ="background-color:#E0EBEB; height:40px;width:100px;"><a href ="#" onclick="call();" style ="text-decoration:none; text-decoration-color:black;"> T-00000031</a></td>
     <td style ="background-color:#E0EBEB; height:40px;width:200px;"> item.FirstName</td>
     </tr>
    }
    </table>
```

Comment: @Html.Action("ProcessTech", "Home"): why can't this call my controller "ProcessTech"? The error: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.